# Getting two navbars to stack in a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using Bootstrap 3 to try to create a website.  I'd like the top to have a header as in this example.  The boxes are just there to give you an example of how my grid is laid out right now.

[image: Example]

In words, what I need it:

- A background image for the entire thing (this is the color part in the image, the yellow and the blue is all one image)
- An empty portion on the left where my Banner will be (this will be part of the yellow & blue image)
- Two navbars on the right (top will be social media links, bottom will be navigation links).  I want them to stack on top of each other, and drop below the left banner at `col-md`.

So far, I've been trying to do this with a grid layout, but it isn't working:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="row" style="background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat; color:#fff; height:100px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="border-color: #F0F; border: dashed;">
      <img src="images/empty.gif" height="100" border="0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="border-color: #F0F; border: dotted;">

      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">You Tube</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id="link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The problems are many, but the main one I'm having issues with is **Getting the two navbars to stack in a column while keeping the left side empty.  When responsive, the two navbars should drop below the empty area**.  Other issues aside, that's what I need help with.

Is using the grid the best way to do this, or is there a better way?

Current status (after altering my code based on answer by @Marc Barbeau ):
Notice that the two navbars do NOT drop down below the banner, AND the bottom navbar doesn't move below the first.

**Col-lg**
[image: Full Size Screen]

**Col-sm**
[image: Small Size Screen]

**How I assume it should look in small view**
Of course, the rest of the menu and the cat picture would be below - off screen.
[image: Simulated Small Screen]

## Edit: Working Version

**index.html**

```
<div class='header'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="logo">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Characters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Archive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">You Tube</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.header{
  background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}
@media(min-width: 300px){
  .header .nav>li {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

#logo{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0); 
  height: 100px;
}
```

```css
.header{
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}
@media(min-width: 300px){
  .header .nav>li {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

#logo{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0); 
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class='header'>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="logo">
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Characters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Archive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">You Tube</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: "Fndige: sisters" is the background image correct? not the cat?

Comment: Yes, the header's background image is the purple text (with the brown line and the oval).  The cat is an image that sits in the next row, under the header (and navigation).

Comment: Working version looks good to me. Created a pen for this also http://codepen.io/mabarbeau/pen/WxxRyQ

Comment: Thanks.  Please add all this (raw code + CodePen) to your answer, so I can mark it solved with the correct answer.  :)

Comment: Updated answer with extra lines to CSS that you may or may not want. Mostly to demo the `background-size` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A few notes

- Drop inline css for readability
- Create a `custom.css` file (Be sure to include after bootsrap css to overwrite styles)
- Learn about [breakpoints](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- Bootstrap breakpoints are going to stack nav under 768px (Use `custom.css` to overwrite)
- id="link" is duplicated see https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

## The code

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div class='header'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="logo">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <nav class="navbar">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="link">Characters</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="link">Archive</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="link">Gallery</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
          <nav class="navbar">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">You Tube</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**custom.css**

```
.header{
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2UgD.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 500px;
}

@media(min-width: 500px){
  .header .nav>li {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px){
  .header{
    background-size: 100vw;
  }
}

#logo{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0); 
  height: 100px;
}

#logo{
  background-color: red;    
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("images/header.jpg");
}
```

#### Edit

Added few extra lines of CSS to shrink background logo image under 500px.

Comment: These do stack in `col-lg` view, but once the screen gets to `col-sm` or smaller, they overlap each other (they also collapse, but that's a different issue) and don't drop below the banner. I'll add images to my question to clarify the issue.

Comment: Your css has header as an id, but the HTML still has header as a class.

Comment: Think I am getting closer to what your looking for. What other changes?

Comment: Yes, I think we're close.  Thanks for your work so far!  You have id `logo` in the css, but haven't used it yet in the HTML.  Is that going to help move the `navbar`s down below the banner?  Also, your first `li` still has `id="link"` instead of `class="link"`

Comment: Made the fixes mentioned above. Sorry for the massive amounts of edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114680/discussion-between-marc-barbeau-and-gaius-augustus).

Comment: I've added the solution you and I worked on to the question.  Please review and add to your solution so I can credit you with the answer.